# Double Boot: Why can I not start Ubuntu?

Tags: boot

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04. I have Windows XP SP3, 2 GB RAM, 1 TB HDD. I did everything that says that I should. I made swap partition and everything. Though, it didn't ask me if I want to import data from xp to Ubuntu while it was installing. In the end, it said that everything installed successfully.

Then it rebooted it itself, it said in tutorial that if Windows start first, it is not big of a deal. I rebooted it again and againg Windows started. I read somewhere that I should hold SHIFT while booting so that GRUB menu start, but it didn't. I also went to BIOS and made a first boot device a HD that Ubuntu is on. NOTHING!

Comment: Which tutorial you were reading?

Comment: This one: http://opensource-sidh.blogspot.com/2012/04/ubuntu-1204-installation-dual-boot-with-windows.html

Comment: are you aware that that tutorial is 2 years old?

Comment: But it is for Ubuntu 12.04. What is the difference if someone makes it today or someone made it 2 years ago. It is the same version of Ubuntu. I can do everything again, but give me some newer tutorial. Or some tutorial that you made.

Comment: Simple, those are bound to have misinformation, also, you don't need a tutorial, just following the in-screen instructions and you will be fine. And, that guide wasn't meant for your type of laptop. On the other hand, we would need more information about your disk, like the output of `sudo parted --list` when you boot from a live CD

Answer (score 0):

Download the Boot Repair ISO, burn that to a CD, run the automated Boot Repair program. It will take care of everything else. If it doesnt work generete a Super Grub2 Disk CD and in a Ubuntu system try with GNU GRUB in this site: http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/, but dont forget BACKUP FIRST !!!

Comment: I did it Joscastel. I did everything with Boot Repair ISO and set no BIOS boot the Ubuntu partition to load first, and now i says: Error: Device not found.
I am starting to get desperate.

Comment: But the boot from the GRUB CD works for both OS windows and ubuntu or not?